# Calling swift from obj c

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to call a function in a swift file from objC. I have tried to "#import project_name-Swift.h" but I get an error -> 
"project_name.h file not found"

The objC file is part of a pod. I don't know if that plays a part in the problem.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Please show how your project is set up. Which module/target is the Swift file in? How is the pod related to the rest of the project?

Comment: Can you share more code?, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a bridge header file (`PROJECT_NAME-Bridging-Header.h`) and add the required headers that XCode can't find in there. You can find the name of that file in the Project's `Build Settings` under `Objective-C Bridging Header`.

This file is auto-magically created when you add an objc file to your Swift project and it is used to call from Swift to Objective-C but apparently, it is needed for the opposite direction too.

The other things you will need to do is add a `#import "PROJECT_NAME-Swift.h"`to your objective-c files. This file is created deep inside the DerivedData project's Build directory and its naming convention is predefined.

Additionally, you will need to extend Swift classes with `: NSObject` and mark them with `@objc` at the beginning of the declaration.

Finally, you will need to mark your classes and methods in Swift as `public` if they are part of a different module. Public is not the default access right.

Answer (score 5):

You need to follow simple below steps to solved out your problem :

1.) first remove your existing bridging header file from project (select file -> right click -> show in finder).

2.) once you delete, then also check its exist in project or not. if not exist, **then prepare new header file at root of your project.**

3.) Now select your project and go in build settings. finf swift compiler - code generation section.

[image]

4.) set **install Objective-C compatibility header** to **YES**

5.) set path in **objective-c bridging header** like : **projectname/bridging-header-filename.h**

6.) now by pressing **alt** key choose product menu and select **clean build folder**. Run your project and now its worked well..!

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste the exact header file name.h file that you are looking to use next to the #import statement. You don't need to import your project_name, you need the header file you want to use. I would have put this in a comment, but I am kinda new here and I guess I am not allowed to comment yet.

example if you want to use SWRevealViewController.h in your project you would need

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
```

in your bridging header file

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Sam! You will need a bridging header to connect Objective C code with swift code. [Here](https://youtu.be/lon5YVMUxHQ) is a video on how to create a bridging header if you don't already have one. If this answer helps you, please click on the checkmark to make it as correct and click on the up arrow to help me out!

Comment: A bridging header is used for calling Obj-C code *from* Swift code, not the other way around.

Comment: Right, unless I'm reading it wrong, he wants to get the obj c code from a pod into his swift project

Answer (score 2):

Simply prepare the bridging header at the root of your project and rebuild the project again.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Create bridging header file in the root of your project and then set path in build settings.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of confusion around, many people answer the opposite question (calling Obj C from Swift).

It's laid out by Apple docs pretty clearly [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c)

One caveat, I created

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

@objc open class MySwiftViewClass: UIView {

        // this next call becomes 
        //    [myDaBar myFuncWithString:aString];  
        @objc open func myFunc(withString:String) {
        let greeting = "Hello!"
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comment, the member function myFunc gets the variable name appended to it.

You can also see it in the generated header file at

```
/Users/<yourname>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TargetName-bthdvookrisgtractdotackhxhjh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TargetName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProductName.build/DerivedSources/Project-Name-Swift.h
```